# Does the verb "be" in a reported speech have to be in the past?

Tags: modal-verbs, past-tense, future-tense

If I'm talking about the *future-in-past*, do I always need to put the verb **be** in the past (***was***) even if this future is *still in the future* relative to the time of utterance?

Here is the situation: I spoke to a friend on June 1, he invited me to dinner on June 3; now it is June 2, and I'm saying:

> He invited me for dinner, but I told him I **was** out of town on June 3 / tomorrow.

Would ***am*** be appropriate here ("I *am* out of town"), taking into account that *June 3 is tomorrow*?

I know that this form is possible in this situation:

> He invited me for dinner, but I told him I **would** / **will** be out of town.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction with *would* is probably the one most frequently used here, and that with *will* next, but the others are all acceptable. At a guess I'd say *was* is probably the **least** frequently used, followed by *am* and *will be*. That reflects the relative infrequency of simple present in non-backshifted use.

It is not entirely irrelevant that all of these except *was* can be contracted, and probably would be in conversation.

> He invited me for dinner, but I told him   I'm    out of town tomorrow.
>   He invited me for dinner, but I told him  I'll be   out of town tomorrow.
>   He invited me for dinner, but I told him  I'd be  out of town on tomorrow.

Among other things, that has the effect of backgrounding the verb and throwing the focus onto *out of town*. In conversation, nobody's going to notice the difference.

ADD:
FumbleFingers points out that there's another option, constructions with *BE going to be*:

> ... I told him I was going to be out of town tomorrow.
>   ... I told him I'm going to be out of town tomorrow.

These two are, I'd guess, on the upper end of the frequency scale.

FumbleFingers also points out that *I was* is often elided in speech. He implies that  the British elision is /aɪz/; in US speech it is /'aɪ(j)əz/ or (in my dialect) /'aəz/. But this is not an "officially approved" contraction; when it's spelled out in writing (typically as "I uz") it is an "eye dialect" form which imputes illiteracy to the speaker.

Comment: Maybe my speech is a bit more sloppy than yours - I'm quite capable of contracting **I was** to **I's**. And I suspect Americans in general may do this more than Brits.

Comment: ...if I actually used **I's** in OP's context, I'd imagine it as short for *"...but I told him  I's [gonna be]   out of town tomorrow"*. That seems to me a reasonable compromise on the tense/mood I'd be looking for.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In my experience, we elide the /w/ but not the vowel, so it's not heard as a contraction. (But the vowel is less clearly marked in Southern dialects like mine, because "I" is monophthongal /a/, not a dipthong, so there's no /j/-glide.) And if we spell it out as eye dialect, it's "uz", never "I's", which is the contraction of "I is", once a stock illiteracy invariably attributed to the Stage Negro and Stage Hillbilly.

Answer (score 0):

In the Great Lakes area where I grew up, I don't remember hearing anything but "I was".  The closest we got to an elision was sort of a very fast "awuz".  As I recall the w was never fully elided.

Also, I lived in England for two years as a teenager and developed a perfect "blue collar" accent.  As I recall our "I was" often dropped the w, as in "oiuz" ("Oiuz there too, wunni"?)

So, @FumbleFingers, my experience differs from your suspicion: when I was American, I didn't elide the w, and when I was a Brit, I did.

As an aside, I have the rather unique experience of being an American who knows exactly what an American sounds like to a Brit, and I don't blame them for making fun of us.  :)